# Is it possible for the Task.Factory.StartNew method to never finish executing?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is it possible for the StartNew method to never finishing executing?

For example, in the following program, without knowing the code in Method1 or Method2, is it possible that the `Console.WriteLine("Tasks Created!");` call is never executed and that this program continues indefinitely without exiting?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MyMethods;

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var one = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Methods.Method1());
      var two = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Methods.Method2());
      Console.WriteLine("Tasks Created!");
   }
}
```

If so, what could cause this?

Comment: Why did someone down vote this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless something goes horribly wrong, `StartNew` will return immediately. So your app will display "Tasks Created!" and then exit, probably before `Method1` and `Method2` have finished executing (and quite possibly before they've even *started* executing).

Sure, it's *possible* that something could go horribly wrong and prevent your code from reaching the `WriteLine` call. Someone could have replaced the default `TaskScheduler` with a buggy implementation. The heap could be corrupted in a way that introduces crazy behavior. There could be an obscure deadlock in the JIT compiler. The computer could be flaky due to malware and/or an overclocked CPU. One of the tasks could call `SuspendThread` on the main thread. Someone could attach a debugger, stop at a breakpoint, and never continue. Use your imagination.

But unless you're prepared to reason about a [total breakdown of normal functioning](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/13/9921676.aspx), you can safely assume that `StartNew` will queue the task and then return.